# Reactor mapping Mono<Boolean> to Mono<Void>

Tags: spring, project-reactor

I have function that return `Mono<Boolean>` and I want to map it to `Mono<Void>` (since this is something I return in my Controller method).

Is there any better way to return such `Mono` instead of `.flatMap { Mono.empty<Void>() }`?

I can't use `.map{ null }` because mapping function cannot accept `null`s.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

yes, simply use `booleanMono.then()`. it only propagates the terminal signals (`onComplete` or `onError`) as a `Mono<Void>`, ditching the `onNext` event.